# When I call controller action using cronjob. It's give fatal error like "Call to undefined function mysqli_init()"

Tags: php, mysqli, cron

When I am calling controller action using cronjob. It gives me error like

[image]

**Here, Is My controller:**

```
class CronCount extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {
    $this->load->model('LogFunctionModel');
    $todayActive = $this->LogFunctionModel->activeCompany(date('Y-m-d'));
    $company_count = $this->LogFunctionModel->otherCount('company');
    $employee_count = $this->LogFunctionModel->otherCount('employee');
    $user_count = $this->LogFunctionModel->otherCount('user_logins');
    $dollars_on_account = $this->LogFunctionModel->userDollar();          
    //log entry         
    $this->load->library('logfunction');
    $this->logfunction->logCountRecord("Companies Active", $todayActive->active);
    $this->logfunction->logCountRecord("Company Count", $company_count->total);
    $this->logfunction->logCountRecord("Employee Count", $employee_count->total);
    $this->logfunction->logCountRecord("User Count", $user_count->total);
    $this->logfunction->logCountRecord("Dollars on Account", $dollars_on_account->balance);
 }

}
```

**System Configuration**

**OS**          : Linux mint

**Database**    : Mysqli

**PHP Version** : 7.1.1

**Project Directory** : /opt/lampp/htdocs/

When I am run controller directly from browser Its work fine. But When I am run using the terminal then it gives me above error you can show in above image. How can I solve that?

Comment: Your web server PHP version/installation and your CLI `php` are different.

Comment: Problems with Environment variables?

Comment: @Jens Asking or telling me?

Comment: @Angel both. It is a possibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP CLI and PHP FPM/php_mod have different configuration (php.ini files). You must to check if the mysqli extension is enabled in the PHP CLI.
Just run `php -i | grep mysqli` and check if `mysqli` is in the output.

Always use a full path to PHP (`/opt/lampp/bin/php`) when you are using XAMPP, because in other way you will use the PHP which is installed directly in your OS (not from XAMPP package). Try to run `/opt/lampp/bin/php /opt/lampp/htdocs/PayrollCommand/index.php croncount`

Comment: Thank you, Late me check

Comment: I uncomment extension=php_mysqli.dll from path /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini

Comment: @Angel On the Linux OS you must use '*.so' files not '*.dll' ('*.dll' files is compiled for the Windows OS).

Comment: I didn't found '.so' extension files in my php.ini

Comment: I installed xampp so, for that I have '.dll' file not an '.so' extension file